# Should I report a fake user account that was just created? If so, how?

Tags: support, users

A user creates an account two days ago. Their profile picture is of a teenage white girl(stolen from the interwebs). Their name is the name of a famous celebrity's youngest daughter(15yo). Their only question and subsequent comments are in broken English (and poor enough quality to have been put on hold), and their profile picture is watermarked with a badge for the 'Allied Arab Forces'.

Is this reportable? If so, how can I?

Comment: Why report it? Report it for what purpose?

Comment: @schroeder For being a fake account, and to prevent nefarious activity. Something that sites like FB do all the time. I had assumed there would be something in the ToS about it. **Edit:** I guess not just 'fake', as my account could be amounted to such, but the intentional deception in using the likeness of others.

Comment: Please note that I will be reporting you for impersonating a cat, French sour cream, or both. Or at least I would, if your posts were also in broken English (but since you write well in my language, you must be legit).

Comment: @JasonC I don't think there are any famous cats named cremefraiche. There is however a famous person with the exact name of said user.

Comment: @cremefraiche Once you have evidence that this person is pretending to be said celebrity's daughter, and that this is causing harm to other users, you may send an email through the standard contact links at the bottom of every page.

Comment: @JasonC Calm down PC bro, this question has already been answered.

Comment: @cremefraiche I believe my previous comment is precisely what can be done. Once you have evidence you *can* contact the team. The contact info *is* at the bottom of the page. These are true. My apologies if that comment was offensive or incorrect! :) If you are asserting that comments cannot be made after answers are posted, that is not correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SE fully allows anonymity in users' public profiles, so that side of things is not an issue here, however there are things you can do:

- if their posts are poor quality, flag them. Mods will sort them out
- if their profile is actually offensive in some way you can also let the mods know

Answer (score 3):

We do not ban users because their account lacks transparency. My profile picture is of an anime character. I choose to add personal details, but there is no necessity for it from SE's perspective.

Facebook requires transparency because the expectation is that the account can be tied to a verifiably real person, due to the social network element to their service. SE has no such expectation or service.

Accounts get banned for their actions and not because they try to hide their real identity. People are free to maintain whatever level of privacy they desire (up to the limits of the ToS).

Comment: I clarified that I don't mean transparency, seeing as I'm using that feature myself, rather 'the intentional deception in using the likeness of others. '. This answer is more talking at me than to me, and does not offer any insight on how to proceed in the future.

Comment: This is not a discussion site, but a Q&A site. You asked a question and I'm providing an answer that is aimed not only at you but others who may have the same question. Rory's answer gives you direction, if you want it, my answer provides the principles behind it.